# C++ runtime error: operator< receiving rhs with ??? value..Surely dumb error I'm missing

Tags: c++, debugging, insert, std

I'm trying to map::insert a key datatype I define (miniVec2ui).. It Breaks during a compare (it has bogus data when comparing).. It's using the standard less functor (i tried with my own, but same problem) - it's passing rhs.x = ??? and rhs.y = ??? basically.   The code is below

```
miniVec2ui v233 = miniVec2ui(x,y);

m_pIdMap->insert(std::pair<miniVec2ui,uint>(v233,(uint)tmpPF.id));// std::pair<const miniVec2ui,uint>(v233, (uint)tmpPF.id) );
//////in other files I defined miniVec2ui,etc. (uint = unsigned int), tmpPF.id unimportant here, uint x; uint y;



typedef std::map<miniVec2ui,uint>       eIdMap;
eIdMap  *m_pIdMap;
m_pIdMap =      new eIdMap;//new std::map<miniVec2ui, uint >;
struct miniVec2ui {
    uint x;
    uint y;
    miniVec2ui(uint inx, uint iny):
                x(inx)
                ,y(iny) { }

    bool operator==(const miniVec2ui& rhs) const {
        return ((x == rhs.x) && (y == rhs.y));
    }
    bool operator!=(const miniVec2ui& rhs) const {
        return ( (x != rhs.x) || (y != rhs.y) );
    }

    bool operator< (const miniVec2ui& rhs) const {
        return ((x < rhs.x) && (y < rhs.y));

   }
    bool operator> (const miniVec2ui& rhs) const {
        return ((x > rhs.x) && (y > rhs.y));
    }

};
```

Specifically - breaking in _function_base.h with __y is {x=???,y=???}... here's the disassembly:

```
...stuff...
#endif

{
  bool operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const { return __x < __y; }
200439C0 55                   push        ebp  
200439C1 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
200439C3 81 EC CC 00 00 00    sub         esp,0CCh  
200439C9 53                   push        ebx  
200439CA 56                   push        esi  
200439CB 57                   push        edi  
200439CC 51                   push        ecx  
200439CD 8D BD 34 FF FF FF    lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
200439D3 B9 33 00 00 00       mov         ecx,33h  
200439D8 B8 CC CC CC CC       mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
200439DD F3 AB                rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
200439DF 59                   pop         ecx  
200439E0 89 4D F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx  
200439E3 8B 45 0C             mov         eax,dword ptr [__y]  
200439E6 50                   push        eax  
200439E7 8B 4D 08             mov         ecx,dword ptr [__x]  
200439EA E8 67 84 F1 FF       call        miniVec2ui::operator< (1FF5BE56h)  
200439EF 5F                   pop         edi   <--------------------- HERE ---------- <<
```

Comment: Remove the cuteness and the bribery from your post please, it's distracting.

Comment: Do not compile 20 minutes after each edit. Make a small program for class you maintain (called unit-test) and compile and debug the test. Compile whole application only when the tests show that the class does what you wanted it to do.

Comment: Test case for class: I should, Oo Tiib.  Lind: Don't answer if it's distracting, dictating taste is worse imo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no idea if it is related to the error you are finding, but your less-than comparison is supposed to implement [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), and it doesn't:

```
bool operator< (const miniVec2ui& rhs) const {
    return ((x < rhs.x) && (y < rhs.y));
}
```

By this logic, `m1` is not less than `m2`, and `m2` is not less than `m1`:

```
miniVec2ui m1(5,5);
miniVec2ui m2(6,5);
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << m1 < m2 << "\n";
std::cout << m2 < m1 << "\n";
```

[std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) uses this condition to determine whether two elements are equal. You probably need something like

```
bool operator< (const miniVec2ui& rhs) const {
    if (x == rhs.x) return y < rhs.y;
    return x < rhs.x;
}
```

You should try to implement `operator>` in terms of `operator<` and `operator!=` in terms of `operator==`.

Comment: ah.. missing all test cases..nice logic sinister. Thanks, and nice elegant solution. +1 .. This will surely cure the problem then. Also, i usually do, but getting complaints when implementing operator!= in terms of operator== ..rather than mess with it, just wrote stand-alones this time. Speed is an issue. I'm choosing this answer. thanks.. stickman noire shooter randomly generated world in cryengine if ure interested..ready in (some form in) two weeks. let me know.